# oracle form developer isnt running in win7

Tags: forms, oracle, oracleforms

i am searching from about 2days but not getting through..

i had install oracle 11g and had install form developer 10g,,,when i run my form  it just install something says installation succcessful when i click ok then show nothing...
i copy jdk7 jre into oracle jinitiasor but it is not working

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbDv1.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ68c.png)

Comment: please click on the blue link to show some images

Answer (score 0):

You can try by installing jre-6u25.